# Sort Array from other array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, arraylist

I got 2 types of array i want to arrange one array from other array. check below arrays

Array 1

```
Array
(
[78445] => Array
        (
            [title] => Never change
        )
[78441] => Array
        (
            [title] => test 123
        )
[78439] => Array
        (
            [title] => test 111
        )
[78893] => Array
        (
            [title] => test 222
        )
[78893] => Array
        (
            [title] => test 555
        )
)
```

Another Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => 78439
    [1] => 78441
    [2] => 78893
    [3] => 78891
)
```

Now i want to sort Array 1 according to Array 2 like below

```
Array
(
[78445] => Array
        (
            [title] => Never change
        )
[78439] => Array
        (
            [title] => test 111
        )
[78441] => Array
        (
            [title] => test 123
        )
[78893] => Array
        (
            [title] => test 555
        )
[78891] => Array
        (
            [title] => test 222
        )
)
```

In this arrays one problem that is you will see array one 0th key is not in Array 2. This array1 (array[0]) is fixed but not showing in array 2.How i do that. In array 1 there is showing only title but in this array i have another keys like descriptions, images etc. How i sort this arrays.

Comment: array_multisort is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(
    "78441"=>array("title"=>"test 123"),
    "78442"=>array("title"=>"test 124"),
    "78443"=>array("title"=>"test 125"),
    "78444"=>array("title"=>"test 126"),
);

$array2 = array(78442, 78443, 78441, 78444);

$sorted = array();
foreach($array2 as $a) $sorted[$a] = $array1[$a];

print_r($sorted);
```

Fiddle: https://3v4l.org/SoMlP

Comment: See my question again, accidentally i was submited my question

Comment: ask a shitty question and then downvote the only person who helps you, you probably won't get any more help.